# How to find the general solution of this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y''+2y'=(1+t)\cos2t$$

I can't seem to find the general solution of the in-homogenous equation. I tried splitting it up into $ y''+2y'=\cos2t$ and $y''+2y'=t\cos2t $ and finding their individual general solutions first but I can't find a solution for $y''+2y'=t\cos2t$. I tried using the ansatz $y=at\cos2t+bt\sin2t$. Is my ansatz wrong? If so, could someone help me?

Comment: It's a first order equation posing $y'=z$

Comment: Since $2i$ is not solution of homogeneous characteristic equation search for a polynomial of same degree than $(1+t)$ before $(\cos(2t),\sin(2t))$. That is find $f(t)=(at+b)\cos(2t)+(ct+d)\sin(2t)$ and you'll find $\{b = 0, c = 1/8, d = 3/16, a = -1/8\}$

Comment: @Isham I think your answer was correct, its an LDE.

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***

Substitute $y'=z$ you get a first order equation:
$$y''+2y'=(1+t)\cos2t$$

$$z'+2z=(1+t)\cos2t$$

Multiply the equation by the *integration factor*, $e^{2t}$:

$$e^{2t}z'+2e^{2t}z=(1+t)\cos(2t)e^{2t}$$

$$(e^{2t}z)'=(1+t)\cos(2t)e^{2t}$$

Just integrate now.

$$e^{2t}z= \int (1+t)\cos(2t)e^{2t}\,dt$$

Comment: I wonder why you deleted it ?:)

Comment: Oh I thought since my english isn't too good that I missed something in the question...it 's simple and better to pose $y'=z$

Comment: Thanks @samijoe for improving my answer